# pyqtgraph: add legend for lines in a plot

Tags: python, pyqtgraph

I'm using pyqtgraph and I'd like to add an item in the legend for InfiniteLines.

I've adapted the example code to demonstrate:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
Demonstrates basic use of LegendItem

"""
import initExample ## Add path to library (just for examples; you do not need this)

import pyqtgraph as pg
from pyqtgraph.Qt import QtCore, QtGui

plt = pg.plot()
plt.setWindowTitle('pyqtgraph example: Legend')
plt.addLegend()

c1 = plt.plot([1,3,2,4], pen='r', name='red plot')
c2 = plt.plot([2,1,4,3], pen='g', fillLevel=0, fillBrush=(255,255,255,30), name='green plot')
c3 = plt.addLine(y=4, pen='y')
# TODO: add legend item indicating "maximum value"

## Start Qt event loop unless running in interactive mode or using pyside.
if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    if (sys.flags.interactive != 1) or not hasattr(QtCore, 'PYQT_VERSION'):
        QtGui.QApplication.instance().exec_()
```

What I get as a result is:
[image: plot image]

How do I add an appropriate legend item?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

pyqtgraph automatically adds an item to the legend if it is created with the "name" parameter. The only adjustment needed in the above code would be as follows:

```
c3 = plt.plot (y=4, pen='y', name="maximum value")
```

as soon as you provide pyqtgraph with a name for the curve it will create the according legend item by itself.
It is important though to call `plt.addLegend()` BEFORE you create the curves.

Comment: **call `plt.addLegend()` BEFORE** thanks, i almost missed that :)

Answer (score 8):

For this example, you can create an empty PlotDataItem with the correct color and add it to the legend like this:

```
style = pg.PlotDataItem(pen='y')
plt.plotItem.legend.addItem(l, "maximum value")
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't find the accepted answer satisfactory

Maybe it used to work in 2015, but with my version (pyqtgraph==0.13.3) :

```py
c3 = plt.plot(y=4, pen='y', name="maximum value")
```

Throw a `TypeError` and

```py
c3 = plt.addLine(y=4, pen="y", name="maximum value")
```

**doesn't** add anything to the legend.

#### My solution :

1. You can use label argument. Put some text close to the line, so it's not in the legend box but can be useful.

```py
c3 = plt.addLine(y=4, pen="y", label="maximum value")
```

2. You add the legend entry manually, but `addLine` generate an `InfiniteLine` which is not compliant. You can however *monkey patch it* with relatively little effort :

```
import pyqtgraph as pg

plt = pg.plot()
plt.setWindowTitle("pyqtgraph example: Legend")
legend = plt.addLegend()

c1 = plt.plot([1, 3, 2, 4], pen="r", name="red plot")
c2 = plt.plot(
    [2, 1, 4, 3], pen="g", fillLevel=0, fillBrush=(255, 255, 255, 30), name="green plot"
)
c3 = plt.addLine(y=4, pen="y", name="maximum value")
# legend.addItem expect fist argument to have opts dict
c3.opts = {"pen": "y"}
legend.addItem(c3, "test")

pg.exec()
```